# BlueStacks will not open from the "Guest" account on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, uac, bluestacks

I have been unsuccessful in figuring out this problem. When I first start the computer up, the BlueStacks daemon will automatically run (the "service"), but if the Guest tries to run it with the administrator not logged in yet, the program will not start -- just shows the loading icon but never does.

If the admin is logged in, the Guest can run BlueStacks; however, I want the Guest to have the ability to run it regardless of the administrator's log-in. I did all of the following and it makes no difference:

1. Gave the Guest full permissions of the entire folder, and all subfolders, done so directly in the Users/Guest class and in the "Admin"/Users class as well; no difference either way.
2. Made certainty that the same shortcut the Guest is using is identical to the one the administrator is using, and it makes no difference -- the Guest cannot start BlueStacks for anything.

I'd post pictures here if I had the reputation, but both shortcuts point to the same "HD launcher" that starts BlueStacks, but the Guest can't do this. Does anyone have any clues as to what the issue is?

Comment: Why are you trying to give ownership of a folder of one user to the guest user.  Just install BlueStacks so all uses can use it.

Comment: It's too late now, isn't it? And what I'd like to know is why the Guest can't launch it, and how I can make the Guest launch it, if it's not too big of a hassle the way it is.

Comment: I was giving ownership because the Guest, by default, has no write permissions to the folder it's in. Rather than giving the entire folder BlueStacks is in permission, I'd rather give just the working directory of it full permission to the guest, in case it was failing to launch for that reason.

Comment: And when I installed it, it gave no option to install for more than one user, from my last experience.